# Gutenberg - dynamically created element: how to set onChange?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

having blocks with many attribues, I'm trying to optimize the code to write things just once.

Because of this I created a PHP array used for default attributes in *register_block_type()*

I pass it into the javascript block part and I'm trying to dynamically create block elements. Everything works.. except the **onChange** callback.

```
// defaults == arraay containing attributes and their data
var controls = [];
$.each(defaults, function(key, val) {
    var type = SelectControl; 

    // key == attribute name
    controls.push(
        createElement( type, {
            value: attributes.key,
            label: val.label,
            onChange: function(e) {
                props.setAttributes({ key : event.target.value});
            },
            options: [...]
        })
    );
});
```

If I change field values, I get

> Error loading block: Invalid parameter(s): attributes

While everything's ok using the precise attribute name (attName in this snippet)

```
onChange: function(e) {
   props.setAttributes({ attName : event.target.value});
},
```

How can I use the dynamic "key" variable?

Comment: `var attrs = {}; attrs[ key ] = event.target.value; props.setAttributes( attrs )`

Comment: Great, absolutely great!

FYI, the final code is:
`onChange: function(e) {
 
 var attrs = {}; 
 attrs[key] = e; 
 props.setAttributes(attrs);
},`
 _event.target.value_ was obviously wrong